# tikz: Ignore one path in bounding box calculation

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to ignore one specific path for the bounding box calculation in the middle of a tikz picture (I need the path only to get an intersection point and had to make it quite long, to be sure that the point exists).

I came up with the following solution but I find it a bit odd-looking. Does something better exist?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,0)-- (2,2);

\begin{scope}
\path [use as bounding box] 
             (current bounding box.south west)
             rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\path (-1,-1)--(5,5); %ignore this
\end{scope}

\fill[red](0,1)rectangle (1,3);
\draw [black] (0,0)rectangle (2,3); %wanted bounding box 
\draw [blue] (current bounding box.south west) 
             rectangle (current bounding box.north east);%current bounding box
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I knew that something more sensible exist somewhere ;-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For such pauses of bounding box calculations, we have two options; the `overlay` option to the scope at the TikZ frontend and the `pgfinterruptboundingbox` environment at the basic layer.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,0)-- (2,2);
\begin{scope}[overlay]
\draw (current bounding box.south west)
             rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\path (-1,-1)--(5,5); %ignore this
\end{scope}

\fill[red](0,1)rectangle (1,3);
\draw [yellow,ultra thick] (0,0)rectangle (2,3); %wanted bounding box 
\draw [blue,thick] (current bounding box.south west) 
             rectangle (current bounding box.north east);%current bounding box
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or using

```
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\draw (current bounding box.south west)
             rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\path (-1,-1)--(5,5);
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
```

both give the following result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. You are giving me a hard time to decide which answer to accept. You were faster and offers two solutions but Andrew addressed the "specific path" in my question. I think I will throw a dice ;-).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Haha, no problem at all.

Comment: @percusse Is there some similar command that will exclude some element of a TikZ image from extending the bounding box without being cropped if it exits the bounding box (as sketched [here](https://sketch.io/render/sk-f9c3ead30121c77759d4627ef9e28aec.jpeg))?

Comment: @Casimir You can add `overlay` key to most (not all) elements to be ignored from bounding box updates

Comment: @percusse I tried adding that to a node as in `\node[overlay,draw,circle,minimum size=16pt,fill=white,postaction={pattern=north east lines},pin={260:$\Gamma_{k,ail}^{(3)}(q_1,\!p_1,\!p_4\!)$}] at (-\radius,0) {};` but to no effect.

Comment: @Casimir This works without any problem `adsfasdgsdfg\tikz{\node[overlay,draw,circle,minimum size=16pt,fill=white,pattern=north east lines]{};\draw(1,0) rectangle (2,1);}adfgadfgdsfg`

Comment: @percusse Yes, but if you readd the `pin={260:$\Gamma_{k,ail}^{(3)}(q_1,\!p_1,\!p_4\!)$}` it fails. And I really need that pin.

Comment: @Casimir try `pin{[overlay].....}`

Comment: @percusse Unfortunately, while this excludes the pins from extending the bounding box, it also crops any part of the pins that falls outside the bounding box.

Comment: @Casimir Then I'm out of ideas. Care to open a question?

Comment: @percusse See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391197/tikz-image-with-overlaid-pins).

Answer (score 27):

You can actually use the key `overlay` on a single path:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,0)-- (2,2);
\draw (current bounding box.south west)
             rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\path[overlay] (-1,-1)--(5,5); %ignore this

\fill[red](0,1)rectangle (1,3);
\draw [yellow,ultra thick] (0,0)rectangle (2,3); %wanted bounding box 
\draw [blue,thick] (current bounding box.south west) 
             rectangle (current bounding box.north east);%current bounding box
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: overlay on a single path]

The `overlay` key sets `\pgf@relevantforpicturesizefalse`.  This is used when adjusting the global bounding box according to the path:

```
\def\pgf@protocolsizes#1#2{%
  \ifpgf@relevantforpicturesize%
    \ifdim#1<\pgf@picminx\global\pgf@picminx#1\fi%
    \ifdim#1>\pgf@picmaxx\global\pgf@picmaxx#1\fi%
    \ifdim#2<\pgf@picminy\global\pgf@picminy#2\fi%
    \ifdim#2>\pgf@picmaxy\global\pgf@picmaxy#2\fi%
    \ifpgf@size@hooked%
      \let\pgf@size@hook@x#1\let\pgf@size@hook@y#2\pgf@path@size@hook%
    \fi%
  \fi%
  \ifdim#1<\pgf@pathminx\global\pgf@pathminx#1\fi%
  \ifdim#1>\pgf@pathmaxx\global\pgf@pathmaxx#1\fi%
  \ifdim#2<\pgf@pathminy\global\pgf@pathminy#2\fi%
  \ifdim#2>\pgf@pathmaxy\global\pgf@pathmaxy#2\fi%
}
```

So from that we see that if the path is `relevantforpicturesize` then the picture bounding box is adjusted to include it, but if not then not.  Thus whilst it is most usual to use this key globally on a picture (or scope), its effect is actually seen path by path and so it can be used on an individual path.

Comment: Thanks. You are giving me a hard time to decide which answer to accept. percusse was faster and offers two solutions but you addressed the "specific path" in my question. I think I will throw a dice ;-).