# TikZ image with overlaid pins

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, bounding-box

In the below TikZ image I'd like the two pins to not extend the bounding box but still be displayed in their entirety (even if parts of them fall outside the bounding box).

[image]

Using the `overlay` option on either the nodes or the pins themselves (as suggested by percusse in the comments to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85851/62340)) unfortunately crops the pins to the bounding box. The same is true if we instead enclose the nodes in a `pgfinterruptboundingbox` or `scope` environment (the latter again with option `overlay`).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\tikzset{
    cross/.style={path picture={\draw[black]
        (path picture bounding box.south east) -- (path picture bounding box.north west)
        (path picture bounding box.south west) -- (path picture bounding box.north east);}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    % Loop
    \def\radius{1.5}
    \draw[very thick] (0,0) circle (\radius);
    \draw[fill=white,cross] (0,\radius) circle (0.175*\radius) node[above=5pt] {$\partial_k R_{k,ij}(p_1,p_2)$};
    \node at (-1.35*\radius,0.75*\radius) {$G_{ij}(p_1,p_2)$};
    \node at (1.35*\radius,0.75*\radius) {$G_{jk}(p_2,p_3)$};
    \node[below] at (0,-\radius) {$G_{ef}(p_3,p_4)$};

    % External lines
    \draw (-2*\radius,0) -- (-\radius,0) node[pos=0.4,below] {$\varphi_a$};
    \draw[->,semithick,yshift=5pt,shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt] (-2*\radius,0) -- (-1.25*\radius,0) node[midway,above] {$q_1$};
    \draw (\radius,0) -- (2*\radius,0) node[pos=0.6,below] {$\varphi_b$};
    \draw[->,semithick,yshift=5pt,shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt] (1.25*\radius,0) -- (2*\radius,0) node[midway,above] {$q_2$};

    % Vertices
    \node[draw,circle,minimum size=16pt,fill=white,postaction={pattern=north east lines},pin={260:$\Gamma_{k,ail}^{(3)}(q_1,\!p_1,\!p_4\!)$}] at (-\radius,0) {};
    \node[draw,circle,minimum size=16pt,fill=white,postaction={pattern=north east lines},pin={280:$\Gamma_{k,bde}^{(3)}(q_2,\!p_3,\!p_4\!)$}] at (\radius,0) {};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I do not understand that first statement. You want them to not be out side the bounding box, but they are allowed to be outside the bounding box?

Comment: I want them to (partly) be outside the bounding box but still be displayed entirely when that particular `standalone` file is inserted in a document. Imagine that diagram as part of a sum of several diagrams. I'm trying to avoid excessive horizontal white space in between these diagrams.

Comment: Standalone is not the way to go here, since it crops off protruding text.  Do you really intend to use \includegraphics in the document, or can this be inserted directly?

Comment: yes standalone clips anything outside the actual bounding box, you can add some border padding. It will work properly in article class

Comment: @JohnKormylo I use `\includestandalone{}` and load the `standalone` package with options `subpreambles=true` and `mode=buildnew` (and shell escape enabled). As far as I understand, this generates a PDF file (updates it if the source file is newer than the PDF) and includes that PDF using `\includegraphics`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @percusse But doesn't border padding add the same white space as if I hadn't bothered with `overlay`?

Comment: Yes, you are loading an image, and something is either in the image or it isn't.  If you want to partially overlap the page, you have to do that AFTER the image is loaded.

Comment: You have two possibilities : one is to include the tikz code and then `overlay` works (the reserved space for the image in the page do not take into account the part that is overlayed); the second solution is to compile your image to pdf using standalone class without `overlay`, and after, when you include the image, you can use `\includegraphics[trim=...]{...}` but you have to set the trim area manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `pin` doesn't produce the result that you want, don't use it and search for alternatives. This is one, two independent nodes for `Gamma ...` with an smaller font and two lines joining them to circles like `pin`.

Note: Probably `pin` can produce a similar results, but I didn't want to consult the documentation right now.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\tikzset{
    cross/.style={path picture={\draw[black]
        (path picture bounding box.south east) -- (path picture bounding box.north west)
        (path picture bounding box.south west) -- (path picture bounding box.north east);}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    % Loop
    \def\radius{1.5}
    \draw[very thick] (0,0) circle (\radius);
    \draw[fill=white,cross] (0,\radius) circle (0.175*\radius) node[above=5pt] {$\partial_k R_{k,ij}(p_1,p_2)$};
    \node at (-1.35*\radius,0.75*\radius) {$G_{ij}(p_1,p_2)$};
    \node at (1.35*\radius,0.75*\radius) {$G_{jk}(p_2,p_3)$};
    \node[below] at (0,-\radius) (gef) {$G_{ef}(p_3,p_4)$};

    % External lines
    \draw (-2*\radius,0) coordinate (xl) -- (-\radius,0) node[pos=0.4,below] {$\varphi_a$};
    \draw[->,semithick,yshift=5pt,shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt] (-2*\radius,0) -- (-1.25*\radius,0) node[midway,above] {$q_1$};
    \draw (\radius,0) -- (2*\radius,0) coordinate (xr) node[pos=0.6,below] {$\varphi_b$};
    \draw[->,semithick,yshift=5pt,shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt] (1.25*\radius,0) -- (2*\radius,0) node[midway,above] {$q_2$};

    % Vertices
    \node[draw,circle,minimum size=16pt,fill=white,postaction={pattern=north east lines}] at (-\radius,0) (cl) {};
    \node[anchor=north east, inner sep=0pt, font=\small] at (-135:\radius) (Gkail) {$\Gamma_{k,ail}^{(3)}(q_1,\!p_1,\!p_4\!)$};
    \draw[thin,gray] (Gkail)--(cl);
    \node[draw,circle,minimum size=16pt,fill=white,postaction={pattern=north east lines}] at (\radius,0) (cr) {};
    \node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt, font=\small] at (-45:\radius) (Gkbde) {$\Gamma_{k,bde}^{(3)}(q_2,\!p_3,\!p_4\!)$};
    \draw[thin,gray] (Gkbde)--(cr);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This shows how to create a partially overlapped image.  The problem with `\includestandalone` is that you can't pass the `\leftoverlap` and `\rightoverlap` values directly.  you might write them out and enter them by hand.  You could also write them to a file and read them in again.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\newlength{\leftoverlap}
\newlength{\rightoverlap}

\tikzset{
    cross/.style={path picture={\draw[black]
        (path picture bounding box.south east) -- (path picture bounding box.north west)
        (path picture bounding box.south west) -- (path picture bounding box.north east);}}
}

\begin{document}

\sbox0{\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Loop
    \def\radius{1.5}
    \draw[very thick] (0,0) circle (\radius);
    \draw[fill=white,cross] (0,\radius) circle (0.175*\radius) node[above=5pt] {$\partial_k R_{k,ij}(p_1,p_2)$};
    \node at (-1.35*\radius,0.75*\radius) {$G_{ij}(p_1,p_2)$};
    \node at (1.35*\radius,0.75*\radius) {$G_{jk}(p_2,p_3)$};
    \node[below] at (0,-\radius) {$G_{ef}(p_3,p_4)$};

    % External lines
    \draw (-2*\radius,0) -- (-\radius,0) node[pos=0.4,below] {$\varphi_a$};
    \draw[->,semithick,yshift=5pt,shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt] (-2*\radius,0) -- (-1.25*\radius,0) node[midway,above] {$q_1$};
    \draw (\radius,0) -- (2*\radius,0) node[pos=0.6,below] {$\varphi_b$};
    \draw[->,semithick,yshift=5pt,shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt] (1.25*\radius,0) -- (2*\radius,0) node[midway,above] {$q_2$};

    % Vertices
    \node[draw,circle,minimum size=16pt,fill=white,postaction={pattern=north east lines},pin={260:$\Gamma_{k,ail}^{(3)}(q_1,\!p_1,\!p_4\!)$}] at (-\radius,0) {};
    \node[draw,circle,minimum size=16pt,fill=white,postaction={pattern=north east lines},pin={280:$\Gamma_{k,bde}^{(3)}(q_2,\!p_3,\!p_4\!)$}] at (\radius,0) {};

    % compute margins
    \coordinate(A) at (-2*\radius,0);
    \coordinate(B) at (2*\radius,0);
    \pgfextractx{\leftoverlap}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{west}}{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}}}
    \pgfextractx{\rightoverlap}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{B}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{east}}}
    \global\leftoverlap=\leftoverlap
    \global\rightoverlap=\rightoverlap

\end{tikzpicture}}%
\fboxsep=0pt
\fbox{% show minipage border
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr \wd0-\leftoverlap-\rightoverlap}
\leftskip=-\leftoverlap
\rightskip=-\rightoverlap
\usebox0
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]